# delete_post_meta not deleting posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a small script that goes through and changes the results from an office ID to an Octa ID and then processes more things. What I don't understand is why I can't seem to get my delete_post_mets to delete the posts.

```
$offices = [];
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $octa_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_octa_id', true);
    $wp_office_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_office_id', true);

    if ($octa_id) {
        $offices[$octa_id] = $post;
    } elseif ($wp_office_id) {
        $offices[$wp_office_id] = $post;
    } else {
        var_dump($post);
        delete_post_meta($post, '');
    }
}
```

Looking at the `var_dump($post)` - I'm receiving 4 results which need to be deleted such as:

```
object(WP_Post)[1545]
  public 'ID' => int 50796
  public 'post_author' => string '16' (length=2)
  public 'post_date' => string '2017-10-10 17:41:43' (length=19)
  public 'post_date_gmt' => string '2017-10-10 22:41:43' (length=19)
  public 'post_content' => string '' (length=0)
```

I need these 4 results to be deleted, but for some reason it won't catch the posts and delete them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think delete_post_meta only deletes custom meta, it doesn't delete the built-in WordPress meta values. Maybe you can specify the values you want deleted manually via the second delete_post_meta parameter? If you want all four deleted you would need four calls to delete_post_meta. I haven't tried this, but worth a shot. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta

Comment: The problem is, I wish I can specify them manually, but I just need to delete all the offices in that else statement that don't have an _office_id or octa_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, was supposed to use `wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);` which deletes the post.